# Migrating ElasticSearch to Elastic cluster on Kubernetes, is there is possible way to send some of the incoming traffic to ECK cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, migration, elasticsearch-5

We are migrating from Elastic Search VM to Elastic cluster on Kubernetes, is there is any possible ways to separate some percentage of the incoming traffic to both ECK cluster and Elastic search on VM’s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it however it depends on the what you are using to Load balancer the traffic and handling the requests.

If you are using the **Nginx** you can use the split traffic and handle the traffic percentages accordingly.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html

If you are using the **Istio** also you can manage it with the

https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/

So it would be mostly depends on what you are accepting the traffic and proxy setup.